# Python: Problem with local modules shadowing global modules

Tags: python

I've got a package set up like so:

```
packagename/
    __init__.py
    numbers.py
    tools.py
    ...other stuff
```

Now inside `tools.py`, I'm trying to import the standard library module `fractions`. However, the `fractions` module itself imports the `numbers` module, which is supposed to be the one in the standard library.

The problem is that it tries to import the `numbers` modules from *my* package instead (ie my `numbers.py` is shadowing the stdlib `numbers` module), and then complains about it, instead of importing the stdlib module.

My question is, is there a workaround so that I can keep the current structure of my package, or is the only solution to rename my own offending module (`numbers.py`)?

Comment: Sorry, should've read TFQ more thoroughly. Anyway, I'm trying to reproduce the problem now, but I can't. How are you executing the code when the error occurs? I can only reproduce it when I'm running code from inside the package.

Answer (score 9):

[absolute and relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) can be used since python2.5 (with `__future__` import) and seem to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I try to avoid shadowing the standard library. How about renaming your module to "_numbers.py" ?

And of course, you could still do:

```
import _numbers as numbers
```