# Reference Issue in Random Module

Tags: python, random, module, reference

My code worked, I changed nothing, and now its highlighted saying it cant reference the module properly

ive tried retyping everything, looking up tutorials, trying SUPER simple lines of code, and my random module in pycharm python 3 is not working

```
import random

value = random.random()
print(value)
```

basically, 
value = random.random() after the dot is highlighted and is saying cannot find reference 'random' in random, like... what??

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace or is this an IDE issue?

Comment: Do you have a file named "random.py" in the same directory as your script?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51819259/1358308 for a similar issue (with a different package name)

Answer (score -3):

If there is a space after the dot(`random. random()` ) remove it.

```
random.random()
```

Try it