# Python's help function executes another program "string.py"

Tags: python

I've been messing around with python a little bit and have created a program saved as `string.py` where I tested out some string functions.
In another program `function.py` in the same directory I wrote this code

```
def say_hi(first = 'John', last = 'Doe'):
    """Say hello."""
    print('Hi {} {}!'.format(first, last))

help(say_hi)
```

which, however, executed the `string.py` program. I found out after some testing that renaming `string.py` to anything else solves the problem and the `function.py` program is executed as intended, but I'd like to understand why the help function executed the other program in the first place.

Comment: What does it mean *"however, executed the string.py program"*? Putting your code in a file and running it returns the expected output (the help message of the above function)

Comment: So if you run `python3 function.py`, you're saying that `string.py` is run? I don't see how that's possible. Are you using an IDE? If so it could still have its build/run target be `string.py` even while you're editing `function.py`, so you need to explicitly run `function.py`. Without more info though or a [mre] we can only take wild guesses as to what your issue is.

Comment: `help()` is apparently importing the standard `string` module, and getting your file instead.  Python's module search path normally has the current directory listed in front of the standard module directories.

Comment: @jasonharper I even created a `string.py` as well and didn't have such issue (Python 3.9)... I believe it must be something like Random Davis mentioned...

Comment: @RandomDavis I wrote the program in SublimeText and executed it in Windows PowerShell with `py function.py`. When I moved `string.py` or `function.py` to a different directory, or kept them in the same directory but renamed `string.py`, the problem resolved itself.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Is that the full code of `function.py`? There are no imports?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Python 3.10.0, and no, no imports. I called the say_hi function a few times after that code snippet but commenting that out didn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry can't reproduce this both Python 3.9 and 3.10. Created a file with the same code as above, created a `string.py` in the same directory - no problems...

Answer (score 3):

You are [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491705/python-problem-with-local-modules-shadowing-global-modules) the name `string`, which is a built-in module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

`string` is a commonly used module. Lots of built-in functions in python run scripts that have `import string` in them, meaning it'll import *your* `string.py` and not the built-in one.

This is just yet another example of why it's a bad idea to name scripts or variables with names that already exist in standard Python.

Comment: That is all well and good. So how come reproducing the same scenario doesn't give the same outcome? I get the expected help message even though there is a `string.py` file in the same directory... Did you also try it and the same happened?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't know what you're doing differently because I'm able to reproduce the issue easily. I put 2 files in a directory; `string.py` (which contains nothing but a print statement), and another script file which contains the example code in this question. When I ran it I got `AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'`. That happened regardless of whether or not I had an `__init__.py` file in the directory.